# Error message while integrating payment options via Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments, backend

Hello fellow Developers,

I need help implementing the Stripe API, which I wanted to add to my project. When trying to acess this page "http://localhost:5005/create-checkout-session" I'm getting the error message "Cannot POST /create-checkout-session".

Do I maybe need to create another route for the SucessPage and also create an additional Page on the Client? So far I was sticking to the documentation on Stripe. There, I copied over all code pieces into my project and started the server. I was expecting that the "Checkout-Page" would be rendered on the Client, but it did not. I also created a "sucess-route", thinking it would regard it as a new route and therefore added the ProductDisplay-Page, but it could acess the route "http://localhost:3000/checkout" either.

**Here's my code:**

**server.js:**

```js
const app = require("./app");
const stripe = require('stripe')('');
const express = require('express');
app.use(express.static('public'));

const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:4242';

// ℹ️ Sets the PORT for our app to have access to it. If no env has been set, we hard code it to 5005
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  line_items: [
    {
      // Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
      price: '{price_1NPSQzLOzeaAZPUpKuWqEfFf}',
      quantity: 1,
    },
    {
      price: '{price_1NTqf0LOzeaAZPUp6UJIr4nB}',
      quantity: 1,
    },
    {
      price: '{price_1NTqgBLOzeaAZPUpc6euz95b}',
      quantity: 1,
    },
  ],
  mode: 'payment',
  success_url: "https://sunshine-wine.netlify.app/order/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
  cancel_url: `${"https://sunshine-wine.netlify.app/"}?canceled=true`,
});

res.redirect(303, session.url);

});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242'));
```

**app.js:**

```js
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
const stripe = require('stripe')('');

app.get('/order/success', async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.query.session_id);
  const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(session.customer);

  res.send(`<html><body><h1>Thanks for your order, ${customer.name}!</h1></body></html>`);
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${4242}!`));


module.exports = app;
```

**App.js (Client):**

```html
<section>
  <div className="product">
    <img
      src="https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"
      alt="The cover of Stubborn Attachments"
    />
    <div className="description">
      <h3>Stubborn Attachments</h3>
      <h5>$20.00</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form action="/create-checkout-session" method="POST">
    <button type="submit">
      Checkout
    </button>
  </form>
</section>
```

**Screenshots:**

[Die Webseite ist nicht erreichbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5fT8.png)

[WineListPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MUPZ.png)

[CheckoutPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T8Ci.png)

[POST-Request Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVdcm.png)

Thank you very much in advance!

Best,
Lukas

Comment: The port hardcoded (you are not using `PORT`) in the code of your server doesn't match the ports you are using in your requests.

Comment: You will need to roll your api keys now. You publicly posted both your live and and test keys: https://stripe.com/docs/keys#rolling-keys.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the PORT to 5005, so it's either taking 5005 or 3000 and now it's actually showing the CheckoutPage, when the Server is started. I'm still not able to navigate to the "http://localhost:5005/create-checkout-session" and it's saying "Cannot POST /create-checkout-session". Do I need to create a route for that and make an API call?